# ArrayBlockingQueue - every month getting queue is full always

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I've producer consumer for processing upload images,

```
imageQueueSize = 150
imageConsumersNumber = 10
```

below init the queue:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Context> imageQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Context>(imageQueueSize);
for (int i = 0; i < imageConsumersNumber; i++) {
    new Thread(new QueueProcessor(imageQueue,executorsFacade)).start();
}
```

below using it:

```
if (queue.offer(context, queueOfferTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    //debug info ..
    return true;
} else {
    log.info("queue {} is full, contentData {} will not be processed", mimeFamilyType,
                context);
    return false;
}
```

below method run implementation:

```
try{
while(true) {
    Context context = queue.take();
    Executor executor = executorsFacade.getExecutor(context.getContentData()
                                                        .getMimeFamilyType());
    executor.execute(context);
}
}catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Exception in run methoud ",e);
        }
```

once every each month, i see in the logs just "queue IMAGE is full"
does anyone knows why this is happening ?
it seems that the take() method is not being executed and the queue is not cleaned.
i can see in the logs that it successfully processed 10K+ requests, but once a month it got stuck.

Comment: Have you checked `executor.execute(context);` doesn't throw exceptions?

Comment: it is surrounded with try-catch, but the queue.take() should remove the head from the array correct?

Comment: Do you catch `Throwable` or something else? Most probably the reason is that consumers end up with exceptions. Once there're no consumers, the queue eventually becomes full.

Comment: Now, after you have updated the question: when an exception occurs, you break out of the loop. You should place the `try-catch` block inside the loop.

Comment: i don't see any "Exception in run methoud" in the logs.

Comment: Then you might get an instance of `Throwable`: `OutOfMemoryError`, `StackOverflowError`, etc. Try catching `Throwable`, log it, rethrow it.

Comment: ok, will try to change it to :  `while(true){
  try{
   Context context = queue.take();
   Executor executor = executorsFacade.getExecutor(context.getContentData().getMimeFamilyType());
   executor.execute(context);
  }catch(Throwable e){
   log.error("Exception in run methoud ",e);
  }
 }`